# Google map on iOS not showing or flickering while dragging or zooming

Tags: ios, css, google-maps

I have Google map embeded in a page. If I open the page on iOS, the map either fails to show (only gray box) or flickers off while dragging or zooming.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the problem was due to parent div having the following css `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`.

If I change this to `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;` the map works perfectly again.